# Excel Userform Listbox Flickering

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to stop a Listbox from flickering when it is updating with data?

I have a listbox on a Multipage on a userform, when the data goes into the sheet it shows in the listbox. However as the data goes into the sheet the listbox flicker, which become a bit annoying.

In my main code, which is a FOR LOOP, i have tried `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` and set it back to true at the end, but nothing seems to work. I can't seem to find the answer on google.

This is my code, which is in the sheet change event. I have NO code in the listbox

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    With ExcelForm.UrlsListBox1
      .ColumnCount = 1
      .ColumnWidths = "600"
      .RowSource = "'" & Sheet2.Name & "'!$A$1:$b$" & Sheet2.Cells(Sheet2.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
   End With
End Sub
```

**FOR INFO -** My user form has several multipages and each page has a listbox each has its own sheet. So I can not just place this code in form initialize, as it has to be relevent to that multipage + listbox when the tab is selected.

**This is an updated code not 100% sure if this is what Zac was advising on**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  With ExcelForm.UrlsListBox1
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then
     .RowSource = "'" & Sheet2.Name & "'!$A$1:$b$" & Sheet2.Cells(Sheet2.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
   End If
  End With
End Sub
```

The Listbox flicking as **NOT** stopped

Also Posted on Mr Excel Today at 1:51pm uk time [Link](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/excel-userform-listbox-flickering.1139563/)

Comment: Your list box is being updated everytime something changes in the sheet. Check if the change is in relevant range (you can use `Intersect` for that). Also, try commenting out `ColumnCount` and `ColumnWidths` lines

Comment: Zac, I have done as you have sugested but the flickering is still there. I had to put the code into the sheet change event otherwise the listbox would not update as the data went in. Do you know of any other method?

Comment: Can you show your updated code?

Comment: this is it `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

   With ExcelForm.UrlsListBox1
   ' .ColumnCount = 1
   ' .ColumnWidths = "600"
    .RowSource = "'" & Sheet2.Name & "'!$A$1:$b$" & Sheet2.Cells(Sheet2.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
  End With
End Sub`

Comment: sorry, but I can't get it to show as a block of code

Comment: Hi, I can get rid of the flickering if I use the a wait time in the For Loop or the main code for the Sheet change events `Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))` the problem is the code become very slow, is there a way to change it to millseconds to run a bit faster. I would rather place it in the sheet change events which is above in my original post

Comment: You can add/update the code in your question. Just makes it easier to read. From what i can see, you haven't added the check for range. Have a look at `Intersect`

Comment: Zac, thanks for your reply. I am very limited in VBA, I am not 100% sure what you mean by `Intersect`

Comment: Just do a search for **intersect excel vba** and you will see. I've done it already. [Click here](https://www.google.com/search?q=intersect+excel+vba&rlz=1C1GCEJ_enGB818GB818&oq=intersect+excel&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l7.6606j1j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) to see the results

Comment: Zac I have updated my code, see above. Not 100% sure if that is what you was advising on, as I am new to VBA. However the flicking has NOT stopped.

Answer (score 0):

As per the feedback, setting **Application.ScreenUpdating=False** dosent work.

I have modified your code to clear ListBox before it updates. Hopefully this might work.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  With ExcelForm.UrlsListBox1
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then
     .Clear
     .RowSource = "'" & Sheet2.Name & "'!$A$1:$b$" & Sheet2.Cells(Sheet2.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
   End If
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: **Tarun,** That was the first thing that I tried. It did not work. The sheet is not flickering the Listbox is flickering.

Comment: I have modified my answer. Please try

Comment: Tarun, thanks for your reply. I tried your modified code, But it gave me an error of `.Clear` message stated `Unspecified Error `. I have since found a possible work around. which does help with the flickering listbox but does slow down the code a bit. The full answer is on Mr Excel website, for which the link is above. I have placed the code as a possible solution, should someone else have a similar problem. I anyone knows of a better fix, please post

Answer (score 0):

This is the work around I am using to fix the ListBox flickering. Full answer is on Mr Excel. Link is above, in my original post, where I have stated that this is also posted on that forum.

**Will slow down the code a bit, but works to reduce or stop the flickering**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim t As Double
With ExcelForms.UrlsListBox1
     .ColumnCount = 1
     .ColumnWidths = "600"
      .RowSource = "'" & Sheet2.Name & "'!$A$1:$b$" & Sheet2.Cells(Sheet2.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row

t = Timer
Do Until Timer > t + 0.8
Loop

End With
End Sub
```

The timer slows down the rate of data being pasted into sheet2, the Listbox then reduces or stops to flicker depending on **t + 0.8** , the higher the number the slower the code, the less the flickering. This is only a work around. If anyone knows a better way please post.